# 'Tuple Variables', what are they and why use them? (code included)

Tags: sql, variables, tuples

```
select c1.customer_name, c1.customer_street
from customer as c1, customer as c2

where c1.customer_street = c2.customer_street

and c1.customer_name <> c2.customer_name;
```

So this code is taken from an exercise I found online. All I can gather from looking at it is that it seems to be creating two separate objects consisting of data from the same place, and it looks like it's then comparing the two objects and returning the result.

I'm approaching it from a programming standpoint because my knowledge of SQL is fairly basic. I just don't understand what is actually happening in this query. Could some explain in detail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn SQL from a tutorial, book, or practice.  Not from poorly written code found on-line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:  That query will give you all the customers who have neighbors in your table.

Line-by-line:

`select c1.customer_name, c1.customer_street`

Ultimately, you're going to get a list of names and streets from the customer table.

`from customer as c1, customer as c2`

You'll be using this table twice, cross-referencing against itself (see below)

```
where c1.customer_street = c2.customer_street
and c1.customer_name <> c2.customer_name;
```

Match each customer in c1 against all the customers in c2, making sure that the streets match and the names differ (<> is the operator for "not equal to").

A simple example:

```
Name        Street:
John Doe    Baker
Mary Sue    Baker
Zach Smith  Dover

JD/Baker    JD/Baker    streets match, name match.  CULL.
JD/Baker    MS/Baker    streets match, name mismatch.  Keep.
JD/Baker    ZS/Dover    no street match.  CULL.
MS/Baker    JD/Baker    streets match, names don't.  Keep.
MS/Baker    MS/Baker    streets match, name match.  CULL.
MS/Baker    ZS/Dover    no street match.  CULL.
ZS/Dover    JD/Baker    no street match.  CULL.
ZS/Dover    MS/Baker    no street match.  CULL.
ZS/Dover    ZS/Dover    streets match, name match.  CULL.

Records kept:

JD/Baker
MS/Baker
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Could you clarify what <> means? and why is it only used for name, and not street as well?

Comment: If <> were used for both name and street, it would dramatically alter the meaning of the query.  Instead of a list of neighbors, you'd end up with basically everyone in the database, with some repetition (in my answer's example, you'd end up with "JD, MS, ZS, ZS" -- the four "no street match" entries in the table because those four rows also don't match on name).